# How to build rows of JSON from a table with one one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, group-by

I have a table `main` like this:

```
create foreign table main (
    "id" character varying not null,
    "a" character varying not null,
    "b" character varying not null
)
```

And I have another table, `not_main`, like this:

```
create foreign table not_main (
    "id" character varying not null,
    "fk" character varying not null,
    "d" character varying not null,
    "e" character varying not null
)
```

Should I want a query whose return is like:

```
   json
0  {"id": "id_main_0", "a": "a0", "b": "b0", "cs": [{"id": "id_not_main_0", "fk": "id_main_0", "d": "d0", "e": "e0"}, {"id": "id_not_main_1", "fk": "id_main_0", "d": "d1", "e": "e1"}]}
1  {"id": "id_main_1", "a": "a1", "b": "b1", "cs": [{"id": "id_not_main_2", "fk": "id_main_1", "d": "d2", "e": "e3"}, {"id": "id_not_main_3", "fk": "id_main_1", "d": "d3", "e": "e3"}]}
```

How should I do it?

I tried:

```
select
    json_build_object(
        'id', m."id",
        'a', m."a",
        'b', m."b",
        'cs', json_build_array(
            json_build_object(
                'd', nm."d",
                'e', nm."e"
            )
        ) 
    )
from main m
left join not_main nm on
    nm."requisitionId" = m.id;
```

But it returns only one element in `cs`:

```
   json
0  {"id": "id_main_0", "a": "a0", "b": "b0", "cs": [{"id": "id_not_main_0", "fk": "id_main_0", "d": "d0", "e": "e0"}]}
1  {"id": "id_main_1", "a": "a1", "b": "b1", "cs": [{"id": "id_not_main_2", "fk": "id_main_1", "d": "d2", "e": "e3"}]}
```

OBS: consider that the constraints of and between `main` and `not_main` are properly modeled, e.g., that I actually have both `id` columns as PKs and that `fk` is references the `id` column of `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want json array aggregation. Basically, you just need to change `json_build_array()` to `json_agg()`, and to add a `group by` clause:

```
select
    json_build_object(
        'id', m.id,
        'a', m.a,
        'b', m.b,
        'cs', json_agg(
            json_build_object(
                'd', nm.d,
                'e', nm.e
            )
        ) 
    )
from main m
left join not_main nm on
    nm.requisitionId = m.id
group by m.id, m.a, m.b
```

Comment: I'm receiving this error: `SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "m.a" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: @HenriqueGuerra: I was assuming that `id` is the primary key of `main`, but it seems not. So we need to add other `main` columns to the `group by` clause: answer updated.